# Will a double equal to an integer always cast to that integer?

Tags: java, casting, double

Will a double equal to an integer always cast to that integer (assuming the double is not one that causes an overflow).  Example: [Math.ceil()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil%28double%29) will return a double that is equal to an integer.  Assuming no overflow, will it always cast to the same integer that it is supposedly equal to?

If not, how can I round up a `double` to an `int` or `long`?

Comment: +1: interesting question.  I would assume the answer is "yes", but there may be some edge cases I haven't considered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since Java types are fixed and [Java doubles have a 52 bit mantissa](http://www.mobilefish.com/tutorials/java/java_quickguide_double.html), they can (with ease) represent a 32-bit Java int without rounding.

Comment: The mantissa represents 53-bits as the top bit is implied to be 1.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it will convert exactly. This is described in [Section 5.1.3](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.3) of the JLS, which mentions

> Otherwise, if the floating-point number is not an infinity, the
>   floating-point value is rounded to an integer value V, rounding toward
>   zero using IEEE 754 round-toward-zero mode...

Since your `double` exactly equals the `int`, the "rounded" value is just the exact same value, but you can read the spec for details.

Answer (score 1):

I believe so, but you might test it yourself:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    int interactions = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int i = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    double d = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    long init = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (; i < interactions; i++, d++)
        if (!(i == (int) Math.ceil(d)))
            throw new Exception("something went wrong with i=" + i + " and d=" + d + ", Math.ceil(d)="+Math.ceil(d));

    System.out.println("Finished in: "+(System.currentTimeMillis() - init)+"ms");
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure if you do that long enough your rounding error will cause a problem. (i.e. as 0.1 cannot be represented exactly)

Comment: -1 using empiric tests for such iteractions is evil as it will in most cases deliver wrong conclusions.

Answer (score 1):

All possible `int` values can be represented by a double without error. The simplest way to round up is to use Math.ceil() e.g.

```
double d = 
long l = (long) Math.ceil(d); // note: could overflow.
```

Comment: All `int` values can, but not all `long` values.

Answer (score 1):

Empirically, the answer seems to be yes - note that it also works with `i2 = (int) d;`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = Integer.MIN_VALUE + 1; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
        double d = i;
        int i2 = (int) Math.ceil(d);
        if (i != i2) {
            System.out.println("i=" + i + " and i2=" + i2); //Never executed
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: amended to start from Integer.MIN_VALUE

Comment: -1 using empiric tests for such iteractions is evil as it will in most cases deliver wrong conclusions.

Comment: The test being total (as in all cases are tested) I don't see the problem. I would agree if it only tested a partial subset of all available integers...

Comment: @jb this is not an empirical argument actually. It proves that the condition holds for all integers by proving it for each integer. (Well, you need to show MIN_VALUE and MAX_VALUE separately to get them all.)

Comment: If we don't know that this behaviour is defined in the JLS it could as well wary between JVM's. So to prove it you'd have to check on all recent and future JVM's. I've just seen people who did this kind of tests and said 'it works', and it worked until they moved to production.

Comment: Different JVM behavior is fair enough

Comment: @jb: Absent access to the source code, empirical test are the only way to investigate whether the documentation can be proven wrong. What else do you suggest? As long as the user understands that empirical tests can prove the documentation wrong and cannot prove the documentation right, but only indicate that it may be right (which assylias does seem to understand: "answer seems to be yes") then empirical tests are the ultimate tool!

Comment: +1 though you should include the boundary case `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett All JVMs are supposed to follow the JLS so finding the answer in the JLS was the only approach that could give a definite answer...